# No response from CanfulFillIntentRequest in alexa

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

```html
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'CanFulfillIntentRequest'

  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    if(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'Myname'){
    return MynameHandler.handle(handlerInput);
      
  }
```

```html
const MynameHandler = {
  
    handle(handlerInput) {
    
    const speechText = 'ALex';
    const repromtText = 'Please respond';
 return handlerInput.responseBuilder 
 .speak(speechText)
.withCanFulfillIntent( 
    {
        "canFulfill":"YES",
 
    })
.getResponse();

}

};
```

```html
{
  "session":{
    "new": true,
    "sessionId":"SessionId.<My Session id>",
    "application":{
      "applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.<Application id>"
    },
    "attributes":{
      "key": "string value"
    },
    "user":{
      "userId":"amzn1.ask.account.<user id>
    }
  },
  "request":{
    "type":"CanFulfillIntentRequest",
    "requestId":"EdwRequestId.<request id>",
    "intent":{
      "name":"Myname"
    },
    "locale":"en-US",
    "timestamp":"2018-10-12T09:36:31Z"
  },
  "context":{
    "AudioPlayer":{
      "playerActivity":"IDLE"
    },
    "System":{
      "application":{
        "applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.<application id>"
      },
      "user":{
        "userId":"amzn1.ask.account.<user id>"
      },
      "device":{
        "supportedInterfaces":{

        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version":"1.0"
}
```

I have been implementing `CanfulFillIntentRequest` for many days, but no luck so far. I am using `alexa-sdk-nodejs` v2. I am not able to build the response for `CanfulFillIntent`. I tried implementing it in an exact way as stated in these documents. 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understand-name-free-interaction-for-custom-skills.html
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/implement-canfulfillintentrequest-for-name-free-interaction.html.

This is my response handler .

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .withCanFulfillIntent(
        {
          'canFulfill': 'MAYBE',
          'slots':{

              }
        })
        .getResponse();
    }
```

```html
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    //return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' || 'CanFulfillIntentRequest'
return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'CanFulfillIntentRequest'
     // && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'Myname' || 'HotelIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    if(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'Myname'){
    return MynameHandler.handle(handlerInput);
      
  }
  };
```

When i run JSON code in manual JSON, It does not respond to the `CanfulFillIntent` request and it gets redirected to error handler code.

Comment: What was the request payload?

Comment: Its CanFulfillIntent request

Comment: Share the request payload as well as the canHandle() function.

Comment: Its hard to read if you put it in a comment. Update those in the original question so that it will be readable.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Share your request payload too.

Comment: The request JSON which is the input to your skill.

Comment: i added in my question

Comment: is your MynameHandler working fine? does it require any slot?

Comment: No its not working fine when i handle the response with CanFulfillIntent, and it gets redirected to my error handler code. I am not using slots as of now.

Comment: Can you share ur MynameHandler too

Comment: Added in my question

Comment: Hi, Check the repository below:
https://github.com/PaulCutsinger/Sample-For-Can-Fulfill-Intent-Request/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js

Answer (score 0):

The `withCanFulfillIntent()` response builder helper method is **only available in [ASK SDK for Node.js (Public Beta)](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/tree/2.x_public-beta)**

Install public beta by

```
npm install --save ask-sdk-model@beta
npm install --save ask-sdk-core@beta
```

or use this in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.1.0-beta.1",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.4.0-beta.1"
  }
```

I tried your code with beta and got expected results:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak>ALex</speak>"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": "<speak>Please respond</speak>"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false,
    "canFulfillIntent": {
      "canFulfill": "YES"
    }
  },
  "userAgent": "ask-node/2.1.0-beta.4 Node/v8.10.0",
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "key": "string value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tested through manual JSON and it worked. Now, how can i check this with echo dot device. how will i come to know whether my skill is invoked or not? Is there any thing else which i need to do from my side? My skill is currently now in development stage, do i need to publish my skill?